# How to install the Minbar Application in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, system-installation, 16.04, unity-dash

Does anyone know how to install the **Minbar** Application in Ubuntu 16.04? (It worked for 14.04+, but the new LTS 16.04 regular Ubuntu no longer has minbar.)

Can we port it to 16.04, or does anyone know a similar application? Does it work with Unity

Thank you so much, appreciate it.

Comment: So I researched a bit, but it appears the the source code is not maintained, but it was last working for Ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone know how we can add it to the Ubuntu 16.04 repository?

Comment: Why don't you ask the devs directly?

Comment: They are no longer maintaining it unfortunately. Here is the webpage in case anyone knows,   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/minbar

Comment: Yeah so Im not sure how hard it is to make it work for Ubuntu 16. Im thinking I need to download their source and compile it but Minbar is a application which uses the Unity System Tray, so It might not work in the new Ubuntu 16.04 :(

Comment: Compiling it from source I dont think will work because I think Ubuntu 16.04 uses a different version of Unity then 14.04. Hmm..

Comment: Maybe there is a way to turn it into a indicator applet? It seems very simple, just a timer that makes popup messages... man... I wish I could figure this one out

Comment: I already contact the minbar team, but no response. Actually you can run it on your Ubuntu 16.04, but the problem is the software keep crashing everytime athan. It seems there's a problem in sound library. So there's only bubble notification

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope that we can run it on Ubuntu 17.10 or higher now as I cant find any applications that do the same thing as Minbar? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the latest binary `minbar_0.2.1-9_amd64.deb` from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/203283785/minbar_0.2.1-9_amd64.deb.
2. Download the latest binary `minbar-data_0.2.1-9_all.deb` from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/203283784/minbar-data_0.2.1-9_all.deb.
3. Install minbar-data binary first before minbar binary.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i minbar-data_0.2.1-9_all.deb
   sudo dpkg -i minbar_0.2.1-9_amd64.deb
   ```

Install required dependencies if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

anyluck in finding this software or a similar one ?
if not i found this software and it's working ok 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/elokabadhan/

Comment: This is not an answer, and the project is not even using english

Comment: i had the same issue here and this is an alternative software that does the same task , and although anyone will need such software will be able to use Arabic but the software also support english

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work successfully on Ubuntu 18.04:

[image: minbar ubuntu 18.04 in 2019 is working]

You need to download and install the packages and dependencies since they are not provided anymore.

Here is an automated script for your convenience.

1. Create a new temp directory to download and install minbar:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/minbartemp
   ```
2. Download and install all packages and dependencies with this automated script:

   ```bash
   cd ~/minbartemp && wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/gstreamer0.10-alsa_0.10.36-2+deb8u1_amd64.deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/gstreamer0.10-plugins-base_0.10.36-2+deb8u1_amd64.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/gstreamer0.10-tools_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2+deb8u1_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/minbar/minbar_0.2.1-7ubuntu2_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/minbar/minbar-data_0.2.1-7ubuntu2_all.deb && sudo apt-get -y install gdebi libxine2-all-plugins && sudo gdebi *.deb
   ```
3. Press <kbd>y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the ALSA (audio) installation.

   [image: minbar ubuntu 18.04 alsa]
4. You may as well add it to your startup applications for your convenience.